# Has anyone secured a .net wcf RESTful service using basic/digest authentication?

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have to secure a WCF RESTful service i'm thinking of doing it in one of two following ways...

1:
By implementing the feature suggested in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479391.aspx) article

2: 
By simply passing a username and password in either the url or the post variables

> What im wondering is has anyone done this? 
>   Is this the way to do it? 
>   If I use the second option can this be accused of being insecure (given that asp.net forms are sent clear text anyway)?

Comment: Forms authentication is secure because of the built-in [encryption handshaking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648341.aspx) it implements. If you're not using HTTPS(SSL) for option 2 then this isn't a secure option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing PII information on the querystring is a definite no-no.

WCF supports basic authentication out of the box. You would need to combine this with transport security (SSL) to ensure the data is safely encrypted over the wire. This is absolutely the lowest common denominator form of authentication on the web and will be supported most widely. To configure your WCF REST service with this kind of security you simply need to configure your service's binding like so:

```
<webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MyBinding">
        <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
           <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
        </security>
    </binding>
</webHttpBinding>
```

WCF supports digest authenticatoin out of the box as well, but only if validated against the AD  of the server which pretty much makes it useless in internet scenarios. So to do Digest Authentication you would need to write your own implementation which hooks into the WCF security runtime. There are some examples of how to do this out there on the web. That said, if you have SSL, there's no real benefit to doing digest authentication over basic authentication.

Comment: hi its not an option to use SSL and AD unfortunately..this is a packaged web app that gets sold to customers. Are you saying that doing digest with WCF Rest is impossible in that case?

Comment: No, it's just that WCF doesn't provide it "out-of-the-box". So you need to write your own Digest authentication implementation or find one that someone else has written. Most of the ones I've seen out there are built on the WCF REST Starter Kit unfortunately. Personally I would recommend against that since Microsoft hs discontinued support for it. It wouldn't take much to take one of those implementations and write your own using "pure" WCF extension points.

Comment: Drew, can you tell me how to find some information about how to 'hook into the WCF security routine'? please